# In need of a logic to create comments in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, comments, laravel-5.6

Ok so the basis is that I want to be able to have comments on each of my post. The comments will have a reply button for each. It’s not multi threaded so one comment will have many replies. Those replies won’t have replies. Also I want to be able to like and dislike a comment/reply. All of this will not be bind to the user model or any of such. The public visitors will be able to add comments and reply to comments but the approval is needed.

So here is the logic I got so far. Am I on the right track here (hoping this post may help someone else as well):

So i create a`Comment` model. And then create a table named `comments`. 
And I create a model named `Reply` and a table named `replies`
And finally, a model name `Like` and it’s table `likes`

So the relationship is: 
`comments` will have many `replies` and `replies` belongs to one `comment`
`replies` & `comments` will have many `likes`.

And now for the logic:

I will use AJAX to call the store function on the `CommentController` to store comments. And I will call the store function on the `ReplyController` to store the replies. As for the likes, `LikeController` store function will store the likes for the comment and reply.

Here is the table structure:

1. Comments table

   - id
   - post_id
   - name
   - email
   - comment
   - approved
   - timestap
2. Replies table

   - id
   - comment_id
   - name
   - email
   - comment (or reply)
   - approved
   - timestamp
3. Likes table

   - id
   - comment_id
   - reply_id
   - like
   - dislike
   - timestamp

Now what I do not understand is, likes table. Is it right to have `comment_id` and `reply_id` and also `like` and `dislike`?
I could call the store function everytime someone clicks the like or dislike and have it stored in the table and update the column if it is a reply or a comment by it’s `id` to the respective id columns. Is the logic right?

Also, if you guys have any suggestions or better and efficient way of doing this, please let me know. 
This is getting too long so I’ll just leave it here.

**Edit**

Also forgot to mention that I am not sure how I will be taking the amount of likes from db to blade and count it. Not with the current structure mentioned above. Also, how to check and see if the person already liked. And if so, don’t let them like again or dislike again. A liked person can not dislike. They can do only one thing.

Comment: @RossWilson Example of what?

Comment: An example of one of the sites that does guest likes/dislikes?

Comment: Ok I was wrong. I’ll edit my question. What about the rest? And if i were to use user model to like? Will i need js to disable the buttons after liking or dislike?

Comment: It is possible to have the appearance of guest "liking", however, it would mean that information is stored in the users browser so all they would need to do to add more votes is use a different browser, use a private tab, or just clear their storage/cookies.

Comment: Yes. That is the exact same thought I had. We could use caching or cookies to like the comment but that’d be useless if the user uses multiple browsers or incognito. Is my table structure right? And what do I need to do if the user is required to like the post after login?

Comment: I'm just writing out an answer for you now. The user would be **required** to like the post?

Comment: Yes. They will be required. But like you mentioned, it is better to login. Otherwise it would make no sense. Also the right way to do it. I mean the comments, reply and likes. Efficiency and logical way of handling both the codes and db queries.

Comment: As in when they login in they then **HAVE** to like a post no matter what?

Comment: No. They are not liking a post. They are liking comments and replies of a comment. And they are not REQUIRED to like or comment anything. It’s their free will. If they are logged in only will the like and dislike button work. Otherwise just display a popup login modal or something.

Comment: Sorry, I typed "post" out of habit.

Comment: No problem. It happens all the time. Too used to writing the word post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend associating comments, replied and likes to a `User` which you are pretty much already doing with comments and replies.

There are ways that you could have a "liking" system that would allow guest usage, however, this would be very easy to get around and ultimately make your "like" stats useless.

---

An example DB structure going forward would be:

**comments and replies**

- id
- post_id // or comment_id if on the replies table
- user_id
- body
- approved
- ( "_at" dates)

**likes**

- id
- likeable_id // id of the comment or reply
- likeable_type // Comment or Reply
- user_id
- liked (boolean)
- ("_at" dates)

The `likes` table is setup to be used as a [Polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) relationship e.g. in your `Comment` model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');
}
```

Then to add a like you would have something like:

```
$like = new Like(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id, 'liked' => true]); 
$comment->likes()->save();
```

There are many different ways you would then check if the current auth user has liked a post, one example would be to have a separate relationship so that you can eager load the results:

```
public function authUserLike()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Like::class, 'likeable')->where('user_id', auth()->id());
}
```

Then if the `auth_user_like` is `null` they haven't already liked that comment.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Detailed and perfect. I will try this and let you know if I need anything else. But in the mean time, let’s let go of the programming side for a moment. Would it be a wise idea to allow guest users to add comments and Approve it from the backend? And to like/dislike, login. Because as per user experience, not many people want to take time to signup just to make a comment.

Comment: @PICKAB00 By the look of the tables in your question, you were going to be getting the `name` and `email` from them anyway. You could always set it so that the `user_id` can be `null` (you would then need to update the `authUserLike` relationship by chaining on `whereNotNull('user_id')`). There isn't anything wrong with having guest comments, however, one draw back would be if you're not getting the `email` address then you wouldn't be able to tie the comment back to the user if they ever did set up an account. Past that point, if it makes sense to you then go for it.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. I will be able to carry it from here. You have given more than enough information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need of the Replies Table just use **parent_id** in comments table. This tutorial might help you get started [Nesting Comments in Laravel](https://appdividend.com/2018/06/20/create-comment-nesting-in-laravel/)